# How do I find column which columns have all numbers in an array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using PHP
I have an SQL Table that looks like so:
[image: SQL Table:]

I am trying to retrieve all rows which contain "9" in the "FAMILY" Column
How would I do so?
Note: The numbers are separated by hyphens "-"

Comment: It won't work if `9` is the last one in `family`

Comment: @1000111 use aggreed not only for that also if it only 9 this will not work

Comment: So what would I need to to do in that case?

Comment: Select * from tablename;   Now use foreach for the records and do it using php code. You can use array functions like strpos() to find element that contains 9.

Comment: Ideally you would normalize your table and put one number per row in combination with the ID in another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this query:

```
select * from table_name where concat('-',FAMILY,'-') like '%-9-%';
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for! Works like a charm!

Comment: Use should accept this as answer if it works for you.

Comment: Now one more question @dipanwitaKundu If I wanted to ask for both numbers how would I execute that? Say: all "9" and "11"

Comment: You can use regex like : '(?=.*4)(?=.*11)'
If you want to search for both 9 and 11

Answer (score 2):

You need to adopt `REGEX` for that I guess.

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE family REGEXP '[[:<:]]9[[:>:]]';`

**Note:** May be it's high time you normalized your data. Otherwise you might find it troublesome even for doing the simplest manipulation on that column.

Have a look at this:

[**Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)